# Unable to import the org.testng.annotations.Parameters; in Eclipse version 2020-06 using TestNG version 7.3.0

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have downloaded Eclipse version 2020-06 and have installed TestNG version 7.3.0 but am unable to import  org.testng.annotations.Parameters; in my Class.

I have a pre-written test that uses the @Parameters annotation:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Parameters {

    WebDriver driver = null;
    
    @BeforeTest 
    public void setup() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Temp\\browserDrivers\\New\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    
    @Parameters({"email", "password"})
    @Test
    public void login(String email, String password) throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get("http://website.com/login?back=my-account");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("section input[name='email']")).sendKeys(email);
        Thread.sleep(3000); //slowing test down for demonstration purposes
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("section input[name='password']")).sendKeys(password);
        Thread.sleep(3000); //slowing test down for demonstration purposes
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button#submit-login")).click();
    }
    
}
```

[Import not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqGW4.png)

[Annotation not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol8OE.png)

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my Class was named the same as the @Parameters annotation. After refactoring my Class name to something different, Eclipse found the import and I could then use the @Parameters annotation.